# 'Text' object has no property 'loc' error in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I made code like below.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=[1, 2, 3]
y = [2, 4, 8]
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.xlabel('X', color='red', fontdict={'size':15}, loc='right') 
plt.ylabel('Y', color='green', fontdict={'size':15}, loc='top')
```

But I got error like this. How can I fix this code?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me.

Maybe check your matplotlib version and your python version.

I have these

```
pip show matplotlib


Name: matplotlib
Version: 3.5.1
```

```
python --version
Python 3.9.10
```